# how to get type of functions which return object

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, vue.js

I was wondering how can get the type from what function returned. The function return object with
two keys: X and y. In my **getItem** function I need only type of X.
I don't want to use the interface **SelectedItems** because in the future I will pass this interface to Pinia store for vue.js to have a global type for this getter.
Any idea how to make it?

```
function getItem(value: string) {
  interface SelectedItems {
    x: animals | null; => object
    y: fruits
  }

  return store.getters['stuff/product'](value) as SelectedItems;
}

function setMapping(aniamals: typeof getItem) { // Here I wouldlike to get to key 'x'
   ...
}
```

Comment: `ReturnType<typeof getItem>["x"]`? It's unclear since your code has invalid syntax..

Comment: You could use `ReturnType<typeof getItem>`, but that will be exactly `SelectedItems`. You could define an alias type for just the field that you require in `setMapping`, e.g. `type ItemX = SelectedItems["x"]`

Comment: @motto yes, I know I can use SelectedItems but as I wrote I Will pass this interface to diferent file - pinia store. So my function will return this type dynamically from Pinia. That's why I want to use typeof what function return. But how can I get to the key?

Comment: @anna Have you tried `ReturnType<typeof getItem>["x"]`?

Comment: @Unmitigated yes, but it doesn't see key x. There is an error.

Answer (score 0):

To get fields of an object, you can use `Object.keys(your_object)` or `Object.entries(your_object)`. This should work even when you are getting your types dynamically from the Pinia Store.

Example:

```
const obj = {a: 1, b: "Hello"} 
Object.entries(obj)
// [[ "a", 1 ], [ "b", "Hello" ]]
```